# Reshapping data in R to a singular matrix

Tags: r

This can be  little difficult on what exactly I want , but I would try my best

Say here is my data in R

```
R1  R2  R3  R4
a   b   a   a
b   d   c   b
            e
```

I want to reshape the data frame so that it would have the data in kind of a singular matrix form,like this

```
    a   b   c   d   e
R1  1   1   0   0   0
R2  0   1   0   1   0
R3  1   0   1   0   0
R4  1   1   0   0   1
```

I assume this is straight forward as it seems easy but my limited knowledge on R is making this a hassle for me

Thanks for your time

Comment: There is no `d` in your sample data. How come it is in the output ? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry this is not my actual data I manually entered the tables above ,

and that was an mistake ,correcting it now

Comment: In the last line of the matrix, the first value should also be one

Comment: If your input data is a set of variable length vectors (R1-R4), you probably want to start with a list of vectors rather than a data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
un <- sort(unique(c(as.matrix(df))))
res <- apply(df, 2, function(x) un %in% x)
rownames(res) <- un
res[] <-  as.numeric(res)
 t(res)
   a b c d e
R1 1 1 0 0 0
R2 0 1 0 1 0
R3 1 0 1 0 0
R4 1 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this, although I don't completely understand the syntax and logic

I assume un is a dataframe to hold unique items in the data 

but what is the 2nd line it gives me an error as  dim(x) must be positive

Comment: Yes, `un` holds the unique values from your data frame. In the second line you are checking columnwise which values from `un` are present in `df`. In order to read the data I replaced the empty cells with NA's, because there cannot be any empty cells in a data frame/matrix in R.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses the [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) library's `ldply` function which is for transforming a list with the result being a data.frame.

```
data_as_list = list(R1=c('a', 'b'), R2=c('b', 'd'), R3=c('a', 'c'), R4=c('a', 'b', 'e'))

result <- ldply(data_as_list, function(item) {
    sapply(letters[1:5], function(letter) letter %in% item)*1})
```

Given a list of character vectors, we generate a row of the resulting `data.frame` from each `item` in the list by asking whether the first 5 letters (a-e) appear in the vector (`item`). Multiplying by 1 is a hack to convert a boolean vector to a 1-or-0 integer vector, if that's really what you want.

Results:

```
  .id a b c d e
1  R1 1 1 0 0 0
2  R2 0 1 0 1 0
3  R3 1 0 1 0 0
4  R4 1 1 0 0 1
```

To fix up the row names:

```
rownames(result) <- result$.id
result <- result[, -which(colnames(result)=='.id')]
```

Now you have:

```
   a b c d e
R1 1 1 0 0 0
R2 0 1 0 1 0
R3 1 0 1 0 0
R4 1 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
 data_as_list = list(R1=c('a', 'b'), R2=c('b', 'd'), R3=c('a', 'c'), R4=c('a', 'b', 'e'))

 stack(data_as_list)
#-----------
  values ind
1      a  R1
2      b  R1
3      b  R2
4      d  R2
5      a  R3
6      c  R3
7      a  R4
8      b  R4
9      e  R4
#---------
 xtabs( ~ values+ind, data=stack(data_as_list) )
#-----------
      ind
values R1 R2 R3 R4
     a  1  0  1  1
     b  1  1  0  1
     c  0  0  1  0
     d  0  1  0  0
     e  0  0  0  1

 xtabs( ~ ind+values, data=stack(data_as_list) )
#----------
    values
ind  a b c d e
  R1 1 1 0 0 0
  R2 0 1 0 1 0
  R3 1 0 1 0 0
  R4 1 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `mtabulate` from the "qdapTools" package. This will work for either a `data.frame` or a `list`... which should make sense, of course :-)

```
library(qdapTools)
x <- mtabulate(df)
x[] <- as.numeric(x > 0)
x
#    V1 a b d c e
# R1  1 1 1 0 0 0
# R2  0 0 1 1 0 0
# R3  1 1 0 0 1 0
# R4  0 1 1 0 0 1
```

Since there are two "d" values in "R2", we use the `as.numeric(x > 0)` to convert to just ones and zeroes. You can drop the first column, which has counted the blanks.

I've used the sample data provided by @barerd:

```
df <- structure(list(R1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), R2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("b", 
"d"), class = "factor"), R3 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"a", "c"), class = "factor"), R4 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "e"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility. This could be improved to scale better.

```
matrix(as.numeric(rbind( ae %in% R1,
       ae %in% R2,
       ae %in% R3,
       ae %in% R4)),4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suppose this is data from a csv file or a table, which you can read into R with read.table() or read.csv().

And you should put it with dput() like:

```
structure(list(R1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), R2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("b", 
"d"), class = "factor"), R3 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"a", "c"), class = "factor"), R4 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "e"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

so that we can put it into R easily.

You can rshape your data with the "reshape" library. There are [many documents](http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html) for reshaping data in R, including the help page, but basically you can transpose() your data, so that columns become rows. You can melt() it, so that each row becomes a unique id-variable combination like:

```
   X1 X2 value
1  R1  1     a
2  R2  1     d
3  R3  1     a
4  R4  1     a
5  R1  2     b
6  R2  2     d
7  R3  2     c
8  R4  2     b
9  R1  3      
10 R2  3     b
11 R3  3      
12 R4  3     e
```

and then, you can cast(data, formula, function) the melted data into any shape. Since you wanted to see the distribution of the values according to R* stuff, I used the following formula:

```
t(cast(melt(t(t), id=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), value~X1, ))[, c(2:6]
```

and got:

```
   a b c d e
R1 1 1 0 0 0
R2 0 1 0 2 0
R3 1 0 1 0 0
R4 1 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x1<-as.character(grep("[a-z]",unique(unlist(df)),value=TRUE)) #df is data
x2<-data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(1:ncol(df),function(i){ifelse(x1 %in% df[,i],1,0)})))
colnames(x2)<-x1
row.names(x2)<-names(df)

 x2
   a b d c e
R1 1 1 0 0 0
R2 0 1 1 0 0
R3 1 0 0 1 0
R4 1 1 0 0 1
```